# How to open React Native Modal with JUST state change (No onPress trigger)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, state

I want a RN Modal to pop up on a Dropdown (RN Material Dropdown) onChangeText call. However, even though the this.state.modalVisibleTwo is changed to true through this function, the modal doesn't show up on the state change.

Is there a way to directly trigger the Modal opening.

I attempted conditional rendering based on this.state.modalVisibleTwo with a Modal that's visible={true} and still nothing.

```
            <Modal
              animationType='slide'
              presentationStyle='overFullScreen'
              transparent={true}
              visible={this.state.modalVisibleTwo}
              ref={component => this.inputModal = component}
              onRequestClose={() => {
              //  console.log('Modal has been closed.');
              }}>
              <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.howMany}>test</Text>
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput2}
                    underlineColorAndroid={'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}
                    maxLength={3}
                    autoCorrect= {false}
                    clearButtonMode="while-editing"
                    keyboardType="numbers-and-punctuation"
                    ref={component => this._textInput2 = component}
                    onChangeText={(q) => this.setState({currentQuantity: q})}
                    placeholder= {strings.enter}/>
                  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Button
                      onPress={() => {
                        this.setModalVisibleTwo(false);
                      }}>
                      {strings.close}
                    </Button>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Button2} onPress={()=> {this.addToCart(order, orderNumber, isCartEmpty)}}>
                      <Text style={styles.addToOrderButtonText2}>{strings.add}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
            </Modal>
```

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>Keyboard.dismiss()} accessible={false}>
                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.bodyTitle}>{strings.schedTitle}</Text>
                  <View style={styles.dropdownContainer}>
                    <Dropdown
                      label={strings.select}
                      data={this.state.services}
                      itemTextStyle={{fontFamily: 'Heiti TC', }}
                      containerStyle={styles.dropDown}
                      baseColor={'#002d62'}
                      itemColor={'rgba(0, 0, 0, .54)'}
                      selectedItemColor={'#002d62'}
                      itemPadding={9}
                      itemCount={7}
                      dropdownPosition={-8}
                      pickerStyle={{width: screenWidth*(3/4), marginLeft: screenWidth*0.032}}
                      onChangeText={(val)=>{this.updateView(val)}}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Button} onPress={()=> {this.addToCart(order, orderNumber, isCartEmpty)}}>
                      <Text style={styles.addToOrderButtonText}>{strings.ok}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.setModalVisibleTwo(true)}}>
                    <Text style={styles.modalTitle1}>{strings.which}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

```
updateView(val){
    //this.inputModal.open();
    if(val == strings.dobox || val == strings.pubox){
      // How Many Boxes
      this.setState({modalVisibleTwo: true, currentService: val, isBox: strings.isBox, updatedDrop: false});
    } else if(val == strings.dobar || val == strings.pubar){
      // How Many Barrels
      this.setState({modalVisibleTwo: true, currentService: val, isBox: strings.isBarrel, updatedDrop: false});
    }
    else{
      // Nothing
      this.setState({currentService: val, currentQuantity: '', isBox: '', updatedDrop: false});
    }
  }
```

I expect the modal to pop up after a modalVisibleTwo state change to true after onChangeText call in Dropdown, but the actual output is a state change and no modal pop up.

Comment: have you tried chaning updateView(val) to updateView =(val)=> {}. Also, in your onPress, try changing it to onPress={()=>this.updateView(val)}

Comment: Thank you for your response Adam, apparently it was an issue with the Dropdown I'm using. Since its animation was still active, the modal did not pop up. So I did setTimeout on the state change and voila it worked!

Comment: Glad you got it working.